# How are you supposed to initialize an Array attribute that I don't know the contents of?

Tags: c++, arrays

I have the following class specified in my code.

```
class Foo{

private: 

int myInt;
Bar myList[10];

public:

Foo(){

myInt = 0;

}

void addBar(Bar b){

this->myList[myInt] = b;
myInt ++;
}

};
```

I am getting the error

> Constructor for Foo must explicitly initialize the member myList which does not have a default constructor.

The thing is I don't know what that list will contain until runtime because the user adds `Bar` objects to the list - and my `Bar` objects don't have a default value, they need to be specified.

How am I supposed to initialize that variable there?

This is the definition of the class `Bar`

```
class Bar{

private:

std::string name;
int number;

public:

Bar(std::string name, int number){
name = name;
number = number;

};
```

Here's what I'm doing on `main()`

```
int main(){

Bar b("Red",1);
Foo f();

f.addBar(b)

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `my Bar objects don't have a default value` If they really don't, then you *must* initialize them in the constructor. Otherwise define a default `Bar` constructor, which would be used to initialize the elements in the array, then you can assign the actual values later. Or, use a `std::vector` instead of a fixed-size array.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'd suggest just using a `std::vector<Bar>` instead of trying to use a raw array. The thing about an array is that you can't leave any of its objects unconstructed. If you really really want to know how to implement this on your own, you do it by first using a *different* type in the array, one that doesn't require any initialization, and then reusing that memory to create and destroy objects as needed.

The "different type" is [`std::aligned_storage_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage). Conveniently, the example on the page is exactly what we want.

```
// template<class T, std::size_t N>
// class static_vector
// T = Bar; N = 10
class Foo {
    // properly aligned uninitialized storage for 10 Bars
    std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(Bar), alignof(Bar)> data[10];
    std::size_t size = 0;
public:
    // compiler-provided default constructor does not initialize data
    Foo() = default;

    void addBar(Bar b) {
        if(size >= 10) throw std::bad_alloc{}; // possible error handling
        // reuse uninitialized memory for a Bar
        new(&data[size]) Bar(std::move(b));
        size++; // if constructor can throw, this must be after the constructor!
    }
    Bar const &operator[](std::size_t pos) const noexcept {
        return *std::launder(reinterpret_cast<Bar const*>(&data[pos]));
    }
    Bar &operator[](std::size_t pos) noexcept {
        return *std::launder(reinterpret_cast<Bar*>(&data[pos]));
    }
    void popBar() {
        if(size <= 0) return; // or whatever
        operator[](--size).~Bar();
    }

    // Have to remember to clean up!
    ~Foo() {
        while(size) popBar();
    }

    // all the other special functions need to be custom...
    // we even have to handle cleanup!
    Foo(Foo const &other) {
        try {
            for(std::size_t i = 0; i < other.size; i++) addBar(other[i]);
        } catch(...) {
            while(size) popBar();
            throw;
        }
    }
    Foo(Foo &&other) {
        try {
            for(std::size_t i = 0; i < other.size; i++) addBar(std::move(other[i]));
        } catch(...) {
            while(size) popBar();
            throw;
        }
    }
    Foo &operator=(Foo const &other) {
        while(size > other.size) popBar();
        std::size_t i = 0;
        for(; i < size && i < other.size; i++) operator[](i) = other[i];
        for(; i < other.size; i++) addBar(other[i]);
        return *this;
    }
    Foo &operator=(Foo &&other) {
        while(size > other.size) popBar();
        std::size_t i = 0;
        for(; i < size && i < other.size; i++) operator[](i) = std::move(other[i]);
        for(; i < other.size; i++) addBar(std::move(other[i]));
        return *this;
    }
    // should also add a way to check size, maybe clear, etc.
};
```

Also, your `Bar` should be written like this:

```
class Bar {
    std::string name;
    int number;
public:
    Bar(std::string name, int number) : name(std::move(name)), number(number) { } 
};
```

and your `main`

```
int main() {
    Foo f; // Foo f(); declares a function!
    f.addBar({"Red", 1});
    return 0;
}
```